# `OnTrack` method not firing in WebRtc go server

Tags: javascript, go, networking, webrtc

- I trying to make website in which there is WebRtc connection between `client` and `server`.`Client` is written in `javascript` and `server` is written in `go`. I have made code for `sdp` exchange and it is working great. I can tell as I have opened a dataChannel between them and it is sending message.
- Now I am trying to send video from client to server. `SDP` exchange is successfull and I can see detail about video in my sdp send from client to server but my `OnTrack` method is not firing.
- I want to able to recive the video from client and without that I cannot.
- I have provided the important code but just in case if I am missing something here is the project [github](https://github.com/Akhilbisht798/StreamYard-Clone).
- This is how i defined my webrtc object in go. Here OnDataChannel method is working fine. Below line of code is in starting of the main function and yes I am using http.
  `

```golang
    config := webrtc.Configuration{
        ICEServers: []webrtc.ICEServer{
            {
                URLs: []string{"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}, // STUN server for NAT traversal
            },
        },
    }

    api := webrtc.NewAPI(webrtc.WithMediaEngine(&webrtc.MediaEngine{}))

    var errPeerConnection error
    peerConnection, errPeerConnection = api.NewPeerConnection(config)
    if errPeerConnection != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error in creating peerConnection")
        return
    }
    peerConnection.OnTrack(func(tr *webrtc.TrackRemote, r *webrtc.RTPReceiver) {
        fmt.Println("Recived Stream from web")
    })
    // Data Channel
    peerConnection.OnDataChannel(func(ch *webrtc.DataChannel) {
        dc = ch
        dc.OnMessage(func(msg webrtc.DataChannelMessage) {
            fmt.Println("Message From Client" + string(msg.Data))
        })
        dc.OnOpen(func() {
            fmt.Println("Data Channel from client is opened")
        })
    })
    peerConnection.OnICECandidate(func(i *webrtc.ICECandidate) {
        fmt.Printf("found new ICE: %v\n", i)
    })
```

- this is How i defined my sdp exchange.

```golang
func connectWebrtc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var offer webrtc.SessionDescription
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&offer)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Invalid SDP offer", http.StatusBadRequest)
    }
    fmt.Println(offer)

    // Exchanging of sdp
    setRemoteErr := peerConnection.SetRemoteDescription(offer)
    if setRemoteErr != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error in Setting Remote Description\n%v\n", setRemoteErr)
        http.Error(w, "Error in Setting Remote Description", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

    answer, errAnswer := peerConnection.CreateAnswer(nil)
    if errAnswer != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to Create Answer\n%v \n", err)
        http.Error(w, "Failed to Create Answer", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

    errSetLocal := peerConnection.SetLocalDescription(answer)
    if errSetLocal != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to set LocalDescription\n%v \n", err)
        http.Error(w, "Failed to set LocalDescription", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

    answerJSON, errEncode := json.Marshal(answer)
    if errEncode != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to encode SDP answer\n%v \n", err)
        http.Error(w, "Failed to encode SDP answer", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    _, err = w.Write(answerJSON)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to send SDP answer\n%v \n", err)
        http.Error(w, "Failed to send SDP answer", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```